# Creating stack class in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

This implementation uses linked list instead of using the built-in list. Does anyone use which version is better for performance?

```
class Stack:
    top = ''
    def __init__(self,data=None,next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
    def pop(self):
        if self.top != None:
            item = self.top.getvalue()
            self.top = self.top.next
            return item
        else:
            return 
    def push(self,data):
        t = Stack(data)
        t.next = self.top
        self.top = t
    def peek(self):
        return self.top.getvalue()
    def getvalue(self):
        return self.data

s = Stack()
s.push('bottom')
s.push('middle')
s.push('top')
popped = s.pop()
print(popped)
top = s.peek()
print(top)
```

Outputs:
top
middle

Comment: Are you doing this as a learning exercise?  Or are you trying to create a new, generally usable data structure? https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Comment: As always, measure in your use case.  (I'd bet it's massively slower than the built-in list type.)

Answer (score 0):

A stack class based on the built-in list will have *much* better performance, e.g.

```
class StackEmptyError(Exception):
    pass

class ListBasedStack(list):
    push = list.append

    def pop(self):
        try:
            return super(ListBasedStack, self).pop()
        except IndexError:
            raise StackEmptyError

    def peek(self):
        try:
            return self[-1]
        except IndexError:
            raise StackEmptyError
```

Measure execution time with the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> stmt = '''
s = Stack()
s.push('bottom')
s.push('middle')
s.push('top')
s.peek()
s.pop()'''

# test built-in list stack class
>>> timeit.repeat(stmt, 'from __main__ import ListBasedStack as Stack')
[1.4590871334075928, 1.4085769653320312, 1.3971672058105469]

# test OP stack class
>>> timeit.repeat(stmt, 'from __main__ import Stack')
[5.018421173095703, 4.971158981323242, 4.990453004837036]
```

The built-in list based class is approx 3.5 times faster than the linked list one.

And, if you are not fussy about having `IndexError` exceptions raised for `Stack` operations, it is faster still (approx 5 times faster):

```
class MinimalistStack(list):
    push = list.append
    def peek(self):
        return self[-1]

>>> timeit.repeat(stmt, 'from __main__ import MinimalistStack as Stack')
[0.9379069805145264, 0.9144589900970459, 0.9160430431365967]
```